# How to calculate percentages inside nested dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have two dictionaries:

```
fruit = {'apple':15, 'mango':12, 'banana':16, 'kiwi':24}
people = {'sam':{'mango':3,'kiwi':12},
          'joy':{'apple':9, 'banana':10, 'kiwi':14},
          'bob':{'mango':8, 'apple':10, 'banana':12}}
```

For every key in the People dictionary, I want to calculate the percentage of values(fruits count) based on the fruit dictionary broken down by individual fruits and all fruits combined.

This is how the calculation is:
{'sam':{'mango':3/12 = 0.25,'kiwi':12/24 = 0.5, 'total': (3+12)/(12+24) = 0.41}

Finally, my output should look like this:

```
people = {'sam':{'mango':0.25,'kiwi':0.5, 'total':0.41},
          'joy':{'apple':0.6, 'banana':0.625, 'kiwi':0.58, 'total':0.6},
          'bob':{'mango':0.66, 'apple':0.66, 'banana':0.75, 'total':0.69}}
```

Can anyone help me how to calculate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a loop, collect the numerator and denominator sums for the grand total and update each value:

```
for d in people.values():
    num = denom = 0
    for k,v in d.items():
        num += v          # sum values for total
        denom += fruit[k]
        d[k] = round(v/fruit[k],2)
    d['total'] = round(num/denom,2)
```

*NB. I'm assuming here that all keys exist in `fruit`. If this in not guaranteed use the `get` method with a default value.*

Output:

```
{'sam': {'mango': 0.25, 'kiwi': 0.5, 'total': 0.42},
 'joy': {'apple': 0.6, 'banana': 0.62, 'kiwi': 0.58, 'total': 0.6},
 'bob': {'mango': 0.67, 'apple': 0.67, 'banana': 0.75, 'total': 0.7}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
fruit = {"apple": 15, "mango": 12, "banana": 16, "kiwi": 24}
people = {
    "sam": {"mango": 3, "kiwi": 12},
    "joy": {"apple": 9, "banana": 10, "kiwi": 14},
    "bob": {"mango": 8, "apple": 10, "banana": 12},
}

out = {
    k: {
        **{f: amount / fruit[f] for f, amount in v.items()},
        "total": sum(v.values()) / sum(fruit[f] for f in v),
    }
    for k, v in people.items()
}

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "sam": {"mango": 0.25, "kiwi": 0.5, "total": 0.4166666666666667},
    "joy": {
        "apple": 0.6,
        "banana": 0.625,
        "kiwi": 0.5833333333333334,
        "total": 0.6,
    },
    "bob": {
        "mango": 0.6666666666666666,
        "apple": 0.6666666666666666,
        "banana": 0.75,
        "total": 0.6976744186046512,
    },
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the use of `**` ?

Comment: @RahulKP `**{ ... }` will *"expand"* (or *unpack*) the dictionary into other dictionary (all keys and values).